# Ремонт крон-планировщика запуска php скриптов (парсера)

Tags: php, mysql, парсер

опыт в php невысок, просьба не пинать за плохой код, многое можно было бы реализовать одной функцией...
Дело в том что имеется скрипт worker.php
Я реализовал логику которая должна поочередно запускать скрипты (если статус задачи в базе 0 - не обработан) при запуске по крону worker.php раз в 1 минуту поочередно, например, крон пнул воркер 1 раз - спарсился один файл, при повторном пинке парсится другой и т.д., исходный код даю

Проблема, во первых файлы при запуске крона запускаются хаотично, нужно чтоб запускалось поочередно impot1,import2...importN
Во вторых, я моя конструкция запуска моих скриптов (file_get_contents) не работает, парсер не запускается, прошу помощи советами, всем благ.

```
include 'db.php';

$skey = '210236'; //секретный ключ чтобы не запустил скрипт чужак

//проверяем текущее время

$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$time = strtotime($datetime);
$time = $time - (5 * 60);
$datecron = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `cronjob` WHERE `date` <= '$datecron' AND `status` = '0'");

//смотрим задачи на парсинг файлов и в соответствии со статусом запускаем парсер с ключом файла

// Перебор результата
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  //echo $row->jobfile;

  switch ($row->jobfile) {
    case 'import0.xml':
      $key = '0';    
      $status = file_get_contents("http://сервер/import/groups.php?key=$skey");
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else {
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }

      exit;
      break;
    case 'import1.xml':
      $key = '1';    
      $status = file_get_contents("http://сервер/import/import.php?number=$key&key=$skey");
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else{
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }       
      exit;
      break;
    case 'import2.xml':
      $key = '2';    
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else{
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }       
      exit;
      break;
    case 'import3.xml':
      $key = '3';    
      $status = file_get_contents("http://сервер/import/import.php?number=$key&key=$skey");
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else{
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }       
      exit;
      break;
    case 'import4.xml':
      $key = '4';    
      $status = file_get_contents("http://сервер/import/import.php?number=$key&key=$skey");
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else{
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }       
      exit;
      break;
    case 'import5.xml':
      $key = '5';    
      $status = file_get_contents("http://сервер/import/import.php?number=$key&key=$skey");
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else{
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }       
      exit;
      break;
    case 'import6.xml':
      $key = '6';    
      $status = file_get_contents("http://сервер/import/import.php?number=$key&key=$skey");
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else{
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }       
      exit;
      break;
    case 'import7.xml':
      $key = '7';    
      $status = file_get_contents("http://сервер/import/import.php?number=$key&key=$skey");
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else{
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }       
      exit;
      break;
    case 'import8.xml':
      $key = '8';    
      $status = file_get_contents("http://сервер/import/import.php?number=$key&key=$skey");
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else{
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }       
      exit;
      break;
    case 'import9.xml':
      $key = '9';    
      $status = file_get_contents("http://сервер/import/import.php?number=$key&key=$skey");
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else{
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }       
      exit;
      break;
    case 'import10.xml':
      $key = '10';    
      $status = file_get_contents("http://сервер/import/import.php?number=$key&key=$skey");
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else{
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл import$key обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }       
      exit;
      break;
    case 'offers.xml':
      $status = file_get_contents("http://сервер/import/offers.php?&key=$skey");
      if($status == 'good'){
        echo "Файл import$key обработан";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `cronjob` SET `status`='1',`date`='$datetime' WHERE `id`='$row->id'");  
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл offers успешно обработан','1,'$datetime');");           
      }
      else{
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('Файл offers обработан c ошибкой','0,'$datetime');");      
      }       
      exit;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Про парсер ничего не сказано. "не работает" - что ожидалось, что возвращает, есть ли ошибки?

Comment: парсер нормально работает, при успешном парсинге взвращает 'good', парсер не при чем, я прошу помощи не с парсером а со скриптом который будет его запускать, проблема как раз в том что file_get_contents не помогает, может Вы знаете другие способы запуска (с передачей get параметров)

Comment: ошибка в том, что file_get_contents как будто не запускает скрипт а просто прпускает его, при запуске worker.php сразу высвечивается 'файл обработан' хотя должна быть задержка выполнения на 1-2 минуты (если бы запустился парсер)

Comment: Ну т.е. он возвращает good не смотря на то, что "не запускается"?

Comment: сам запуск парсера должен прохдить с задержкой, если просто в браузере его запустить то все отлично он крутит, парсит и потом good, а когда через file_get_contents то как-то сразу все происходит быстро и не понятно, алгоритм запуска через браузер и через file_get_content принципиально одинаков? или там ограничения есть какие-то?

Comment: а на сервере, где парсер, можете логи посмотреть? ваш скрипт вообще обращается на сервер?

Comment: щас сейчас все посмотрю, спасибо за подсказку, и все же повторить вопрос хочу алгоритм запуска через браузер и через file_get_content принципиально одинаков? или там ограничения есть какие-то? есть какая-либо разница в этих 2-х методах запуска скрипта?

Comment: в принципе одинаков. он должен вернуть либо содержимое страницы либо false в случае ошибки. т.е. если он возвращает good, то не из воздуха же он это берет. значит слово good возврашено запросом с сервера

Comment: да знаю, я так и делал парсер чтоб good возвращал, все разобрался, ошибка была по глупости, простите, дело в другом было, у меня 2 сервера, на одном скрипт редактировал а на другом запускал, скрипты в одинаковых дирректориях, все работает оказывается, прошу прощения и спасибо большое, в следущий раз буду внимательнее смотреть в адресную строку где запускаю скрипт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> при запуске по крону worker.php раз в 1 минуту поочередно, например, крон пнул воркер 1 раз - спарсился один файл

Видимо нужно ограничить выборку 1-м файлом, у вас получаются все

> нужно чтоб запускалось поочередно impot1,import2...importN

Видимо нужно отсортировать выборку по имени файла

```
$result = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM `cronjob` 
    WHERE 
        `date` <= '$datecron' 
         AND `status` = '0' 
    ORDER BY `jobfile` 
    LIMIT 1
");
```

Comment: спасибо, Ваш запрос мне помог!